# запрет сохранения если в форме не введны все поля

Tags: html, jsf

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно запретить сохранение если в форме были заполнены не все поля и под полями высветить сообщение о том что поля не заполнены. Типо такого. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую JS, JSF и т.д.

Вот то что есть сейчас. Это кнопка сохранить, к списку и поле англ.

```
<tr>
                <th>
                    <label for="form:engLink">#{webAuthMsg.banner_link_eng}</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <h:inputText value="#{component.engLink}" id="engLink" maxlength="255"
                                 title="#{webAuthMsg.banner_link_eng}"/>
                    <h:message for="engLink" styleClass="error" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <h:commandLink value="#{commonMsg.to_list}" action="list" styleClass="list command" immediate="true"/>
        <h:commandLink value="#{commonMsg.save}" action="#{component.save}" styleClass="save command"/>
    </div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой прикольный атрибут [required](https://webref.ru/html/input/required)([css](https://webref.ru/css/required))

Ваш пример:

```
<table ?? не знаю что у Вас здесь написано ?? >
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="form:engLink">#{webAuthMsg.banner_link_eng}</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <h:inputText value="#{component.engLink}" id="engLink" maxlength="255"
                         title="#{webAuthMsg.banner_link_eng}" required/>
            <h:message for="engLink" styleClass="error"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Если нужно стилизовать это дело - в css также доступен селектор [:invalid](https://webref.ru/css/invalid).